# Call Pod by IP from another Pod

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-pod

I've developed a python script, using [python kubernetes-client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/) to harvest Pods' internal IPs.

But when I try to make an http request to these IPs, from another pod, I get `Connection refused` error.

I spin up a temporary `curl` container:

```
kubectl run curl --image=radial/busyboxplus:curl -it --rm
```

And having the internal IP of one of the pods, I try to make a `GET` request:

```
curl http://10.133.0.2/stats
```

and the response is:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.133.0.2 port 80: Connection refused
```

Both pods are in the same `default` namespace and use the same default `ServiceAccount`.

I know that I can call the Pods thru the `ClusterIP` service by which they're load-balanced, but this way I will only access a single Pod at random (depending which one the service forwards the call to), when I have multiple replicas of the same Deployment.

I need to be able to call each Pod of a multi-replica Deployment separately. That's why I'm going for the internal IPs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you missed the port number here

It should be like this

`curl POD_IP:PORT/stats`

Comment: Well, as always, the issue was something super small... :D